# Position of dialog box not in the center of the web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following php and java script am working on,as soon as the label_dialog box pops-up ,it opens to the top left corner of the browser even though I have it as center..can anyone help to figure out why it is not in the center?

php code:-

```
            <div id="label_dialog" title="Submission Details">
              <center><table border='1' align="center">
              <div id="submission_details" name="submission_details"></div>
                </table></center>
            </div>
```

javascript code:-

```
    $("#label_dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: true,
        position: ['center'],
        width: $( window ).width()*3/4,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "Edit": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Submit": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('#submitted_gerrits_form').hide();
                $('#gerrits_form').hide();
                $("#component_form").hide();
                $("#submitted_gerrits_table").hide();
                $("#gerrits_form").hide();
                $("#check_gerrits").hide();
                $("#main_form_su_validation").hide();
                $("#contacts_form").hide();
                $("#dependencies_form").hide();
                $("#su_release_form").hide();
                $("#submission_note_form").hide();
                $("#submission").hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line:

```
position: ['center'],
```

If you check the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) you would see that you are not using the correct format; position needs to be an [object](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/). If you wanted to be centered (which is default), you would use something like:

```
{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }
```

However since that's the default you should be able to just omit it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing `<center></center>` from your code and use css or `style-"..."`

Comment: why is that?i inherited this code from someone else,so maintaining the same,if it is any better I will change,also why does   `<div id="submission_details" name="submission_details"></div>` mean?is there any documentation like Mike pointed below to check?

Comment: @user2125827 You'll have to be more specific about "what does it mean".